# Xdcmp and Unixware, I login and...fail immediately

Tags: unixware

I want to access to Unixware 7 Desktop from Slackware 15 client.

The ports are opened in firewall (6000-6009 and 177 udp and tcp)
I can telnet the remote ports

```
telnet 192.168.201.2 6000
Trying 192.168.201.2...
Connected to 192.168.201.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

for 177 I use nmap to check avaliability

```
nmap -p177 -sU -P0 192.168.201.2
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-12-13 03:55 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.201.2
Host is up (0.00021s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
177/udp open  xdmcp
MAC Address: ************
```

This is the server X line on Unixware

```
/usr/bin/X11/X :0 -noexit -auth /var/dt/Aun...
```

Xaccess allow all

```
*           # grant service to all remote displays


*               CHOOSER BROADCAST       #any indirect host can get a chooser
*.mydomain.priv
```

From client I start the login and...judge by yourself

```
Xephyr -query 192.168.201.2 -screen 800x600  :1
```

[image]

No errors logged on Unixware machine, any suggestion? Thanks

EDIT1: I have also tried

```
X -query 192.168.201.2 :1
```

same thing

EDIT 2: Logging with no privileged user = same thing.

EDIT 3: Xev report nothing

```
xev -display :0
```

EDIT 4: Finally some logs found

$HOME/.dt/accesslog

```
dtsession: Unable to exec /usr/bin/X11/kinput2.
```

$HOME/.dt/errorlog

```
Fri Dec 15 03:33:05 2023
dtsession: Unable to exec /usr/bin/X11/kinput2.
  [ENOENT (2)] No such file or directory

Fri Dec 15 03:33:05 2023
dtsession: Unable to exec /usr/bin/X11/kinput2.
  [ENOENT (2)] No such file or directory

Fri Dec 15 03:35:03 2023
dtsession: Invalid display name - exiting.

Fri Dec 15 03:49:10 2023
dtsession: Invalid display name - exiting.
```

$HOME/.dt/sessionlogs

```
Xlib: connection to "slack64.mydomain:1.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified
```